# posmax: like argmax but gives the position(s) of the element x for which f[x] is maximal

Tags: math, function, functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica, utilities

Mathematica has a built-in function [ArgMax](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArgMax.html) for functions over infinite domains, based on the [standard mathematical definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max).

The analog for finite domains is a handy utility function.
Given a function and a list (call it the domain of the function), return the element(s) of the list that maximize the function.
Here's an example of finite argmax in action:
[Canonicalize NFL team names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471029/canonicalize-nfl-team-names/472213#472213)

And here's my implementation of it (along with argmin for good measure):

```
(* argmax[f, domain] returns the element of domain for which f of 
   that element is maximal -- breaks ties in favor of first occurrence. *)
SetAttributes[{argmax, argmin}, HoldFirst];
argmax[f_, dom_List] := Fold[If[f[#1]>=f[#2], #1, #2]&, First[dom], Rest[dom]]
argmin[f_, dom_List] := argmax[-f[#]&, dom]
```

First, is that the most efficient way to implement argmax?
What if you want the list of all maximal elements instead of just the first one?

Second, how about the related function posmax that, instead of returning the maximal element(s), returns the position(s) of the maximal elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dreeves, you're correct in that `Ordering` is the key to the fastest implementation of ArgMax over a finite domain:

```
ArgMax[f_, dom_List] := dom[[Ordering[f /@ dom, -1]]]
```

Part of the problem with your original implementation using `Fold` is that you end up evaluating `f` twice as much as necessary, which is inefficient, especially when computing `f` is slow. Here we only evaluate `f` once for each member of the domain. When the domain has many duplicated elements, we can further optimize by [memoizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the values of `f`:

```
ArgMax[f_, dom_List] :=
  Module[{g},
    g[e___] := g[e] = f[e]; (* memoize *)
    dom[[Ordering[g /@ dom, -1]]]
  ]
```

This was about 30% faster in some basic tests for a list of 100,000 random integers between 0 and 100.

For a `posmax` function, this somewhat non-elegant approach is the fastest thing I can come up with:

```
PosMax[f_, dom_List] :=
  Module[{y = f/@dom},
    Flatten@Position[y, Max[y]]
  ]
```

Of course, we can apply memoization again:

```
PosMax[f_, dom_List] := 
  Module[{g, y},
    g[e___] := g[e] = f[e];
    y = g /@ dom;
    Flatten@Position[y, Max[y]]
  ]
```

To get *all* the maximal elements, you could now just implement `ArgMax` in terms of `PosMax`:

```
ArgMax[f_, dom_List] := dom[[PosMax[f, dom]]]
```

Comment: I should note that as an alternative to memoization, you can always just use `DeleteDuplicates` instead, when that makes sense for your application.

Comment: You probably want to wrap this in a First so that, eg, ArgMax[Abs, {1,-3,2}] returns -3 instead of {-3}.

Answer (score 0):

For posmax, you can first map the function over the list and then just ask for the position of the maximal element(s).  Ie:

```
posmax[f_, dom_List] := posmax[f /@ dom]
```

where `posmax[list]` is polymorphically defined to just return the position of the maximal element(s).
It turns out there's a built-in function, [Ordering](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html) that essentially does this.
So we can define the single-argument version of posmax like this:

```
posmax[dom_List] := Ordering[dom, -1][[1]]
```

I just tested that against a loop-based version and a recursive version and Ordering is many times faster.
The recursive version is pretty so I'll show it off here, but don't ever try to run it on large inputs!

```
(* posmax0 is a helper function for posmax that returns a pair with the position 
   and value of the max element. n is an accumulator variable, in lisp-speak. *)
posmax0[{h_}, n_:0] := {n+1, h}
posmax0[{h_, t___}, n_:0] := With[{best = posmax0[{t}, n+1]},
  If[h >= best[[2]], {n+1, h}, best]]

posmax[dom_List] := First@posmax0[dom, 0]
posmax[f_, dom_List] := First@posmax0[f /@ dom, 0]
posmax[_, {}] := 0
```

None of this addresses the question of how to find *all* the maximal elements (or positions of them).
That doesn't normally come up for me in practice, though I think it would be good to have.