# Efficient way to remove empty lists from lists without evaluating held expressions?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562902/efficient-way-to-remove-empty-lists-from-lists) an efficient way to remove empty lists (`{}`) from lists was suggested:

```
Replace[expr, x_List :> DeleteCases[x, {}], {0, Infinity}]
```

Using the [Trott-Strzebonski in-place evaluation technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633236/replace-inside-held-expression/6633334#6633334) this method can be generalized for working also with held expressions:

```
f1[expr_] := 
 Replace[expr, 
  x_List :> With[{eval = DeleteCases[x, {}]}, eval /; True], {0, Infinity}]
```

This solution is more efficient than the one based on `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
f2[expr_] := expr //. {left___, {}, right___} :> {left, right}
```

But it has one disadvantage: it evaluates held expressions if they are wrapped by `List`:

```
In[20]:= f1[Hold[{{}, 1 + 1}]]

Out[20]= Hold[{2}]
```

So my question is: what is the most efficient way to remove all empty lists (`{}`) from lists without evaluating held expressions? The empty `List[]` object should be removed **only** if it is an element of another `List` itself.

---

Here are some timings:

```
In[76]:= expr = Tuples[Tuples[{{}, {}}, 3], 4];
First@Timing[#[expr]] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}
pl = Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]; 
First@Timing[#[pl]] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}

Out[77]= {0.581, 0.901, 5.027}

Out[78]= {0.12, 0.21, 0.18}
```

Definitions:

```
Clear[f1, f2, f3];
f3[expr_] := 
  FixedPoint[
   Function[e, Replace[e, {a___, {}, b___} :> {a, b}, {0, Infinity}]], expr];
f1[expr_] := 
  Replace[expr, 
   x_List :> With[{eval = DeleteCases[x, {}]}, eval /; True], {0, Infinity}];
f2[expr_] := expr //. {left___, {}, right___} :> {left, right};
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
Clear[f3];
f3[expr_] := 
 FixedPoint[
  Function[e, 
   Replace[e, {a___, {}, b___} :> {a, b}, {0, Infinity}]],
   expr]
```

It seems to live up to the specs:

```
In[275]:= f3[{a, {}, {b, {}}, c[d, {}]}]

Out[275]= {a, {b}, c[d, {}]}

In[276]:= f3[Hold[{{}, 1 + 1, {}}]]

Out[276]= Hold[{1 + 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the solutions you mentioned with a minimal performance hit and maintain the code unevaluated by using a technique from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747742/uses-for-mapall/5749275#5749275) post, with a modification that the custom holding wrapper will be made private by using `Module`:

```
ClearAll[removeEmptyListsHeld];
removeEmptyListsHeld[expr_Hold] :=
  Module[{myHold},
     SetAttributes[myHold, HoldAllComplete];
     Replace[MapAll[myHold, expr, Heads -> True],
        x : myHold[List][___] :> 
           With[{eval = DeleteCases[x, myHold[myHold[List][]]]}, 
             eval /; True], 
       {0, Infinity}]//. myHold[x_] :> x];
```

The above function assumes that the input expression is wrapped in `Hold`. Examples:

```
In[53]:= expr = Tuples[Tuples[{{}, {}}, 3], 4];
First@Timing[#[expr]] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, removeEmptyListsHeld[Hold[#]] &}

Out[54]= {0.235, 0.218, 1.75, 0.328}


In[56]:= removeEmptyListsHeld[Hold[{{},1+1,{}}]]
Out[56]= Hold[{1+1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just a bit late with this one. ;-)

Though rather complicated this tests about an order of magnitude faster than your `f1`:

```
fx[expr_] :=
 Module[{s},
  expr // 
   Quiet[{s} /. {x_} :> ({} /. {x___} -> (# /. {} -> x //. {x ..} -> x) &)]
 ]
```

It does not evaluate:

```
Hold[{{}, 1 + 1}] // fx
```

> ```
> Hold[{1 + 1}]
> ```

#### Timings

```
expr = Tuples[Tuples[{{}, {}}, 3], 4];
First @ Timing @ Do[# @ expr, {100}] & /@ {f1, fx}

pl = Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}];
First @ Timing @ Do[# @ pl, {100}] & /@ {f1, fx}
```

> ```
> {10.577, 0.982}  (* 10.8x faster *)
>
> {1.778, 0.266}   (* 6.7x faster  *)
> ```

#### Check

```
f1@expr === fx@expr
f1@pl   === fx@pl
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
> ```

#### Explanation

The basic version of this function would look like this:

```
{} /. {x___} -> (# //. {} | {x ..} -> x) &
```

The idea is to first reduce the expression with `//. {} | {x ..} -> x` and then use the [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121) with an empty expression to remove all instances of `x`, as though they were replaced with `Sequence[]` but without evaluation.

The first change is to optimize this somewhat by splitting the replacement into `/. {} -> x //. {x ..} -> x`.  The second change is to somehow localize `x` in the patterns so that it does not fail if `x` appears in the expression itself.  Because of the way *Mathematica* handles nested scoping constructs I cannot simply use `Module[{x}, . . . ]` but instead have to use the injector pattern again to get a unique symbol into `x___` etc., and `Quiet` to keep it from complaining about the nonstandard use.

Comment: +1 This solution is really esoteric. Could you please explain which value `x` takes on different levels of nested `ReplaceAll` and `ReplaceRepeated`? And what happens to the variable `s`?

Comment: @Alexey for some reason I didn't get notified of this comment.  If you look at the "basic version" it's not too complicated.  `(# //. {} | {x ..} -> x)` replaces any empty lists with `x`, and any lists like `{x, x, x}` also with `x`.  Then this becomes the right and side of a replacement `{x___} ->` which "injects" a certain expression to replace every `x`, with the *trick* being `{} /. {x___}` such that `x` is replaced by nothing. (continued)

Comment: A second injection is used in the `Module` to replace every literal `x` in the pattern with a unique symbol to form a function like: `{} /. {s$152___} -> (#1 /. {} -> s$152 //. {s$152 ..} -> s$152) &` which is what actually does the job.  I don't have time to give a longer explanation and I may not for a few days so this will have to suffice for now; I hope it helps.