# Problems interpreting input cell box expressions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I convert an arbitrary box specification extracted from a cell expression into an input expression?

This came up as a problem with my answer to [Save Mathematica code in `FullForm` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8282605/211232).  In that context, pattern matching was being used to extract box specifications from notebook expressions read using `Import`.

I thought that `ToExpression` or `MakeExpression` would do the job of box interpretation, but in some circumstances they do not.

Consider an input cell that contains the expression:

```
StringForm["a = ``", 1]
```

The cell expression for such a cell looks like this:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"StringForm", "[", 
  RowBox[{"\"\<a = ``\>\"", ",", " ", "1"}], "]"}]], "Input"]
```

I can take the `BoxData` subexpression from this cell and use `ToExpression` to obtain the same output as if I had evaluated the original cell:

```
ToExpression @
  BoxData[
    RowBox[{"StringForm", "[", 
      RowBox[{"\"\<a = ``\>\"", ",", " ", "1"}], "]"}]]
```

But now consider the following input expression:

``` StringForm["a = ``", 1] ```

You'll have to look closely to see the difference: the `a` is in italics.  Here is the corresponding cell expression:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"StringForm", "[", 
  RowBox[{"\"\<\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"a\",
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) = ``\>\"", ",", " ", "1"}], "]"}]], "Input"]
```

If I evaluate this cell normally, I get the expected result.  But if I try applying `ToExpression` to the `BoxData` subexpression like before:

```
ToExpression @
  BoxData[
   RowBox[{"StringForm", "[", 
    RowBox[{"\"\<\!\(\*
  StyleBox[\"a\",
  FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) = ``\>\"", ",", " ", "1"}], "]"}]]
```

an error occurs:

```
StringForm::string : String expected at position 1 in StringForm[]\) = '',
FontSlant->"\~\(\*\nStyleBox["a Italic, 1].
```

The same kind of error occurs for many, if not all, of the inline string box escape sequences.  I've tried explicitly specifying the form to `ToExpression` and `MakeExpression`, but I get the same error.  Which brings me to my question...

What do I have to do to emulate the way Mathematica interprets the boxes from an input cell expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a bug. Here is a work-around that worked on a couple of examples I tested:

```
Clear[toExpression];
toExpression[bd_BoxData] :=
   ToExpression[bd /.
      s_String :>
         StringReplace[
            StringReplace[s, "\n" :> ""],
            ShortestMatch[(start : "\(\*") ~~ body__ ~~ (end : "\)")] :> 
                   StringJoin[start, StringReplace[body, "\"" :> "\\\""], end]
         ]
   ];
```

For example, we start with your case:

```
In[747]:= 
 BoxData["\"\<\!\(\*
    StyleBox[\"a\",
       FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) = ``\>\""]//toExpression

Out[747]= a = ``
```

If we examine the cell now, it is:

```
BoxData["\<\"\\!\\(\\*StyleBox[\\\"a\\\",FontSlant->\\\"Italic\\\"]\\)\ = ``\"\>"]
```

instead of

```
BoxData["\"\<\!\(\*StyleBox[\"a\",FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) = ``\>\""]
```

(which is the initial one with newlines removed). And, I'd argue, this is what it should have been from the start. Now:

```
In[746]:= ToExpression@
   BoxData["\<\"\\!\\(\\*StyleBox[\\\"a\\\",FontSlant->\\\"Italic\\\"]\\) = ``\"\>"]

Out[746]= a = ``
```

So this already works fine.

I don't know how universal this work-around it, but it seems to work for examples I tried. The main problem was that, when "stringifying" things like `a` and `Italic`, it should have been `\\\"a\\\"` and `\\\"Italic\\\"` rather than `\"a\"` and `\"Italic\"` - the escapes for escapes themselves were missing.

Comment: @WReach Note that my initial solution wasn't entirely right - it was failing on more complex expressions, as I just discovered. I modified it a bit - now it seems to work correctly.

Comment: Your updated version handles all of the cases that I have collided with.  I'll hold off on the "accept" for a little while longer in case there are other ideas forthcoming.  I'm inclined to agree that there is a bug here, but I can't shake the feeling that I am missing something fundamental... or perhaps it is just a vain hope that the parser is not using hidden functions unavailable to us.

Comment: @WReach I think this is the same type of information loss as one that happens in the following simple example: `ToExpression[ToString["a"]] // Head` (returns `Symbol`). `ToExpression` reduces the level of "stringification" (don't know how to put it better) for a string. So, to have a string after `ToExpression`, we should have used here `"\"a\""`. The case at hand  is the same by nature, but we are talking about one level deeper: "level 2" stringification where the bug seems to be that only "level 1" was used.

Comment: @WReach Congrats with the 10K, by the way!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I am not sure what you're trying to do, but I suspect you will need to use the FrontEnd itself for processing.  Here is a generic example:

```
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`CellPrint[
  BoxData[RowBox[{"StringForm", "[", RowBox[{"\"\<\!\(\*
         StyleBox[\"a\",
         FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) = ``\>\"", ",", " ", "1"}], "]"}]]
]
```

However, I don't know what format you actually want to get.

Comment: In the context of the original linked question, the goal was to reconstitute an input expression from its cell representation obtained using `Import` or `NotebookGet`.  I was very surprised to discover that `ToExpression` was not adequate for the task.